# How to declae more than one package in the manifestfile

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

in my android project, i have two different packages and each package contains some activities.

Now, i want to declare all the activities in the manifestfile.xml, but the problem is it is only allowed to declare one package in the manifestfile.xml as shown in the follwoing code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.xxx.xxx">
```

how to declare more than one package in the manifestfile.xml

Comment: I doubt if we can do that.

Answer (score 0):

lest assume **com.package1.package**  as first package & **com.package2.package** as second package. if both has "MainActivity.java files. here is how you declare

```
 <manifest package="com.package1.package">
        <application>
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
            <activity android:name="com.package2.package.MainActivity"></activity>


        </application>
    </manifest>
```